# How to replace a column name header- Python/Airflow/Redshift/PostgresSQL

Tags: python, mysql, airflow, psycopg2

I am running a SQL statement and fetching the results(column/header) and I am trying to collect only the headers that have _check at the end of it and then do a .replace command to get a list of the newly named columns without the _check at the end.

Here is my code:

```
pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgre_conn_id="postgres_default", schema='schema1')
connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
col_query = "select * from schema.table"
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(col_query)

#fetchall to dictonary
desc = cursor.description
column_names = [col[0] for col in desc]
data = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

for x in column_names:
    if x='updated_check':
       x.replace('_check','')


connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to replace the name of the columns that have _check in them and them put them inside a list? Any help would be appreciated. I am using airflow, python, mysqldb, and  psycopg2